# SQL-Server instance issue in IIS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

I have created a website in which I am authenticating user as per the user and password present in the database. It was working fine until I uploaded on the IIS server.

I am getting the following error.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


The database 'C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\WEBSITE11\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 655. This server supports version 612 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
Could not open new database 'C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\WEBSITE11\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebSite11\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The database 'C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\WEBSITE11\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 655. This server supports version 612 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
Could not open new database 'C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\WEBSITE11\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebSite11\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Source Error: 



Line 16:     {
Line 17:         // Verify that the username/password pair is valid
Line 18:         if (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password))
Line 19:         {
Line 20:             e.Authenticated = true;


 Source File:  c:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebSite11\LoginPage.aspx.cs    Line:  18 

Stack Trace: 



[SqlException (0x80131904): The database 'C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\WEBSITE11\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 655. This server supports version 612 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
Could not open new database 'C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\WEBSITE11\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebSite11\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +6675958
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +688
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4403
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +84
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +55
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +368
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +6704598
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +6705099
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions) +610
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +1049
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +74
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6707667
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +2192
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +116
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1012
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6712291
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +152
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +229
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder.Open(HttpContext context, Boolean revertImpersonate) +150
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation) +4880234
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String& password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32& failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime& lastActivityDate) +3888545
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat) +186
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password) +195
   LoginPage.Login1_Authenticate(Object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebSite11\LoginPage.aspx.cs:18
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +160
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +93
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +84
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3804




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18067
```

I tried to search that i need to downgrade the version of the database but dont know how exactly. I have sql-server 2008.

I dont have the liberty to create the entire database into the downgrade instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a script for database and then create that database in SQL Server where you want to use this. Here is the reference link for that.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2810/how-to-migrate-a-sql-server-database-to-a-lower-version/